# Accessing data inside json object error

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I'm trying to access some data inside a json object and i'm somewhat confused with the issue i'm facing. I have a json object like the following

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
"image": null,
"video": null,
"author": null,
"publisher": "Microlink Documentation",
"title": "React | Microlink Documentation",
"date": null,
"lang": "en",
"description": null,
"logo": "https://microlink.io/favicon.ico",
"url": "https://docs.microlink.io/sdk/getting-started/react/"
}
}
```

Here i have wrote the code so that `console.log("meta",metaData.data);` logs out

```
"image": null,
"video": null,
"author": null,
"publisher": "Microlink Documentation",
"title": "React | Microlink Documentation",
"date": null,
"lang": "en",
"description": null,
"logo": "https://microlink.io/favicon.ico",
"url": "https://docs.microlink.io/sdk/getting-started/react/"
```

But i want to take the `title` separately. So i've used `console.log("meta",metaData.data.title);` But i'm getting a error saying

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined**

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: It should work. Can you provide the code written above this JSON object?

Comment: `console.log("meta",metaData.data);` should include the word `meta` at the begining of the output but I can't see it in the output you've provided. Are you sure that the second printout is from that call to `console.log`?

Comment: As @Jayesh mentioned, there is nothing obviously wrong with what you have shown in your question.  Can you post more of the contextual code? It is not obvious for example if the two console.log statements are  truly in the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is absolutely right but should be wrapped in the condition like

```
if(metaData.data){
console.log(metaData.data.title);
}
```

because you are getting the data from an async call